# ReactJs - componentWillReceiveProps is not triggered on returning the same state from reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am using react and react-redux in my app. While submiting form data, i'm calling the API in redux action and dispatch it to reducer. Reducer returns 
"{ ...state, message : action.message }" which in turn invokes componentWillReceiveProps life-cycle method as my component is connected to the store. Everything is working perfectly as of now.

Again when user fill the form and submit's second time, the same action is repeated. But now the componentWillReceiveProps function is not getting triggered. Reason behind this is reducer returns the same state "{ ...state, message : action.message }" that resembles the previous state data. If I add a new object with random numbers in the reducer like below, everything is working.

> { ...state, message : action.message, random : Math.random() }

I know that componentWillReceiveProps is triggered when the store changes. But how to trigger the componentWillReceiveProps method second time when the form is submitted?

This is my componentWillReceiveProps method where i show success message to the user.

```
componentWillReceiveProps = props => {
    if( typeof props.message !== "undefined" && props.message !== "" ){
        //Show a success message notification bar
        this.state._notificationSystem.addNotification({
            title : 'Success message',
            message: 'Form has been successfully submitted',
            level: 'success',
            position : 'br',
            autoDismiss : 10
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` triggers when props are changed. Do you want to change the props or not? Sounds to me like you don't, but you have some code in there that you want to run. In that case, this code might be in the wrong place.

Comment: The state returned from reducer will be mapped to props using react-redux, by that way first time state and props are changing but second time its returning the same state like previous. Same actions called subsequently will return the same state as previous. In my case its a success message after the data is stored in server ( { ...state, message : action.message } ).

Comment: Redux state is mapped to props. If the state doesn't change, props don't change - `componentWillReceiveProps` isn't being called. Makes perfect sense with it's own logic. If I understood what you want, you shouldn't be asking how to make that function run, you should be asking how to show a success message.

Comment: I hope this is not an anti-pattern, but I needed exactly this once as well. I ended up passing another prop with a number which I incremented every time I wished the component to re-render.

Comment: Exactly @ViktorSeč, I'm doing the same thing for time being( Is it supposed to be like this? ). Added another prop with math.random(). But i asked this question to find the perfect way to do this.

Comment: @Prem, no idea, I'd also like to know. To be honest it doesn't seem _right_. Incrementing or multiplying by -1 is safer than math.random().

Answer (score 2):

`react-redux` let you force re-renders of wrapped component even if it props didn't change. To do so you have to pass `{ pure: false }` option as a 4th argument of `connect` function.

Fast example can be found [here](https://jsbin.com/jiqiwaduvi/edit?js,output).

**But** in your case it looks like an anti-pattern. Fistly, it will be updated upon *all* state changes even ones then have nothing to do with form submitting. Secondly, I would say that this kind of logic (i.e. "let's show notification on success") should live inside action which performs the transaction, not Component.